# How to set colorControlHighlight (ripple color) for all the icons inside toolbar programmatically?

Tags: android

I know there is a way to set theme to toolbar in xml like this:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"/>
```

and in the styles:

```
<style name="ToolBarTheme">
            <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
        </style>
```

But is there a way to set it programmatically or using main app theme specifically for toolbar, not just override colorControlHighlight in the main theme(because it will affect other Views as well)?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution that works for me. I have a CustomToolbar class that extends Toolbar class. And in constructor I am using ContextThemeWrapper with my toolbar theme:

```
class CustomToolBar : Toolbar {

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ToolBarTheme))

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ToolBarTheme), attrs) 

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.ToolBarTheme), attrs, defStyleAttr)

}
```